# SOQL to schema converison

Tags: soql, schema

```
public static map<id,RecordType> MapRecordtype = new Map<id,RecordType>([SELECT id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType where sobjecttype ='move__c' and 
                                       Developername in('Assignment','Draft','Domestic_Draft','LTST_Draft','MX_Domestic','MX_Domestic_draft','Termination','International_Relo','Localization','J1',
                                       'Back_To_Back','Repatriation','PAM','US_Domestic_Relo','CHN_Domestic_Relo','CHN_Domestic_Draft')])
```

Can we write schema for above query?

Comment: Please do not repost questions that are essentially identical. I have closed the previous one as a duplicate of this one, as it contains a little bit more information.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a look into [getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName)

Here is the sample code that fetche recordTypeId for account, where developer name of recordtype is `Broker`.

```
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> developerNameVsRecordTypeInfos = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();
System.debug(developerNameVsRecordTypeInfos.get('Broker').getRecordTypeId());
```